# 3000W e-bike with four 48V batteries that I am running in parallel and series giving 106V need to regulate or limit my voltage to 72V

Tags: voltage-regulator

What options are there to reduce the voltage from 106V to 72V? I have four 48V 13Ah 30 ampere batteries hooked up in parallel and series. Anything will work as long as it's 72V.

Comment: A synchronous buck is the way to go.

Comment: 3000W buck is ridiculous, expensive, inefficient, and useless for driving a motor. Get a motor controller that can handle the voltage instead. And don't ride high voltage in the rain...